# Optimización en querys y código, CPU no baja del 100% cuando termina una consulta en proyecto C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cpu

**Antes de empezar: El código no lo hice yo, me "cayo de arriba" así como está, el proyecto utiliza C# ASP.NET, pero el código que les muestro pareciera que es Java. Proximamente voy a dejarlo 100% como C#, pero tengo otras tareas mas importantes.**

Buenas a todos. Tengo 8 cores, de los cuales 5 son consumidos en medio dia (Se consumen al 100%), lo que ocurre es que no se liberan los 5 cores cuando los usuarios terminan de utilizar la aplicación, por lo que sospecho que queda un loop abierto y que no cierra. Para eso, utilicé `using(...){ .... }` para asegurarme que se cierren. Ésto hizo que en vez de consumir 7, consuma 5, y ahora aunque en todas las `querys` utilizo el `using`, me sigue consumiendo muchisimo los cores y no sé porqué. Yo sospecho de las siguientes lineas de codigo que les dejo, ya que están mal optimizadas, pero no sé si será por esto.:

```
  try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVariables.connectionSQL))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using(cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection))
                    {                            
                        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                PedidoViewModel pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                pedido.setNumeroPedido(reader["Pedido"].ToString());
                                pedido.setNumeroEntrega(reader["Entrega"].ToString());
                                pedido.setNumeroRemito(reader["Remito"].ToString());
                                pedido.setPathImagen(reader["Path"].ToString());
                                fecha = reader["Fecha"].ToString().Split(" ");
                                pedido.setFecha(fecha[0].ToString());
                                pedido.setHora(fecha[1].ToString().Replace("-", ":"));
                                pedido.setCodigoImagen(reader["Entrega"].ToString());

                                if (reader["numTramite_tr"].ToString() == null || reader["numTramite_tr"].ToString() == "NULL" || reader["numTramite_tr"].ToString() == "")
                                {
                                    if (reader["ImgFrenteDni_tr"].ToString() != null || reader["ImgFrenteDni_tr"].ToString() != "NULL" || reader["ImgFrenteDni_tr"].ToString()
                                        != "" && reader["ImgDorsoDni_tr"].ToString() != null || reader["ImgDorsoDni_tr"].ToString() != "NULL" || reader["ImgDorsoDni_tr"].ToString() != "")
                                    {
                                        ViewData["NoHayTransportista"] = null;
                                        pedido.setNumeroTramite("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setNombre_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setApellido_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setSexo_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setDocumento_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setEjemplar_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setFechaNac_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setFechaEmision_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setCod_tr("Sin Datos");
                                        pedido.setImgFrenteDni_tr(reader["ImgFrenteDni_tr"].ToString());
                                        pedido.setImgDorsoDni_tr(reader["ImgDorsoDni_tr"].ToString());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ViewData["NoHayTransportista"] = "No hay datos de transportista";
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    pedido.setNumeroTramite(reader["numTramite_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setNombre_tr(reader["nombre_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setApellido_tr(reader["apellido_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setSexo_tr(reader["sexo_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setDocumento_tr(reader["documento_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setEjemplar_tr(reader["ejemplar_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setFechaNac_tr(reader["fechaNac_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setFechaEmision_tr(reader["fechaEmision_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setCod_tr(reader["cod_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setImgFrenteDni_tr(reader["ImgFrenteDni_tr"].ToString());
                                    pedido.setImgDorsoDni_tr(reader["ImgDorsoDni_tr"].ToString());
                                }

                                ViewData["NumeroPedido"] = pedido.getNumeroPedido();
                                ViewData["NumeroEntrega"] = pedido.getNumeroEntrega();

                                listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }                                       
                }

                return listaPedidos;
            }
```

Todas las conexiones que realizo a la bd, son abiertas con using, por lo que son cerradas automaticamente. El problema no es que haya un alto nivel de consumo del cpu, sino que el problema es que éste no esté bajando, se queda en 100% sin bajar, llenando el resto de cores que dispongo. Las `querys` son muy simples, nada elaborado, como mostré, en todas las consultas solamente selecciono las columnas que vaya a utilizar, muy pocas utilizo `*`, ya que no requiero de todas las columnas de la tabla.

Ahora mismo estoy probando con `Thread.Sleep(1000)`; para darle un poco de respiero al `while`, pero no sé si ésto va a ayudar a bajar el nivel del uso de cpu.

El problema de ésto, creo yo, es que me vuelve más lenta la aplicacion, por eso quiero saber si me podrian ayudar a resolver éste problema.

Consulta 1: Obtener registros en un rango de fechas

```
 consulta = "SELECT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha from Entrega e INNER JOIN Pedido p ON e.Entrega = p.Entrega WHERE e.Fecha BETWEEN '" + desdeFecha + " 00:00:00' AND '" +
                    hastaFecha + " 24:00:00' GROUP BY e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito ORDER BY e.fecha ASC";
```

Consulta 2: Contar cantidad de Entregas

```
consulta = "SELECT COUNT(Entrega) AS 'cantidad' FROM Entrega WHERE Entrega = '" + reader["Entrega"].ToString() + "'"
```

Consulta 3: Obtener todos registros de un determinado Pedido (numero pedido, entrega, remito, datos de transportista, fotos)

```
consulta = "SELECT * from Pedido p INNER JOIN Entrega e ON p.Entrega = e.Entrega left JOIN transportista t ON p.Entrega = t.entrega_tr WHERE p.Pedido = '" + identi + "'"
```

Explain en las querys:

Consulta 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta 3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esas son las `querys` que más se utilizan. Las probé en la base de datos y aunque traigan +100 registros, funciona rapido.

Todos los servidores que utilizamos son virtuales, no utilizamos fisicos. Ésta sobrecarga del CPU solo ocurre en ambiente de Produccion, no de Testing.

En ambiente de Testing funciona correctamente,no queda pegado en 100%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION**:

Implementé el uso de Loggs para saber qué es lo que  se está utilizando, qué querys se ejecutan al momento de que un cpu llega al 100%.

Esperé a que por lo menos 2 cores se llenen al 100% y estas son las coincidencias en ambos:

- Coincidencia 1: Salida del try-catch:

> The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream

- `InsertConexionMySql` (querys simples)

querys que utiliza `InsertConexionMySql`:

```
private bool InsertConexionMySql(string consulta)
{
    try
    {
        using MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVariables.connectionSQL);
        connection.Open();
        using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        using MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        connection.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
        Logger.Debug("Insert en la base de datos MySql || Funcion: InsertConexionMySql()");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: InsertConexionMySql()");
        return false;
    }
}
```

- SELECT * FROM Pedido WHERE Remito = '" + remitoDeVuelta[0] +
  remitoDeVuelta[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynu5M.png) + "' AND Entrega = '" + dividir[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynu5M.png) + "';
- `INSERT INTO Pedido (Pedido, Entrega, Remito) VALUES " + " ('" + dividir[0] + "','" + dividir[1] + "','" + remitoDeVuelta[0] + remitoDeVuelta[1] + "');`
- `INSERT INTO Entrega (Entrega, Path, Fecha, NombreUsuario, GrupoUsuario) VALUES" + " ('" + dividir[1] + "','" + ruta + "','" + dividir[3] + " " + fechaSinPunto[0] + "','-','-');`
- Coincidencia 3: Funcion `GuardarNombreYApellido()`:

public string guardarNombreYapellido([FromBody] dynamic jsonObject)
{

```
    try
    {
        string consulta;
        bool respuestaBD;
            try
            {
            JsonElement entrega = jsonObject.GetProperty("entrega");
            JsonElement nombre = jsonObject.GetProperty("displayName");
            JsonElement grupo = jsonObject.GetProperty("userGroup");
            consulta = "UPDATE Entrega SET NombreUsuario = '" + nombre.ToString() + "', GrupoUsuario = '" + grupo.ToString() + "' WHERE Entrega = '" + entrega.ToString() +
                "' AND NombreUsuario = '-' AND GrupoUsuario = '-'";
            respuestaBD = InsertConexionMySql(consulta);

            if (respuestaBD)
            {
                Logger.Debug("Guardar Nombre y Apellido return 1 || Funcion: guardarNombreYapellido");
                return "1";
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Debug("Guardar Nombre y Apellido return 0 || Funcion: guardarNombreYapellido");
                return "0";
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: guardarNombreYapellido() 1er catch");
            return "0";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: guardarNombreYapellido() 2do catch");
        return "0";
    }}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta y el escenario está complejo, ven a la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Si tuviera que adivinar diría que tu problema está en la base de datos (o en la consulta), el código que muestras no tiene nada de extraordinario más allá del tufillo a java que tú mismo mencionas.

Comment: Etonces dejame que pongo algunas consultas de ejemplo de cómo las estoy haciendo

Comment: Es esta la misma pregunta que hiciste en noviembre?

Comment: Parecida... No me acordaba que habia hecho una pregunta como esta

Comment: Un `EXPLAIN` de las consultas ayudará a discernir el origen del problema; compara el resultado entre Producción y Testing. ¿Hacen pruebas de estrés en Testing?. Es difícil que un sleep ayude, ¿ayuda poner topes donde hay tráfico?.

Comment: Tus consultas tampoco son pesadas, además indicas que son pocos datos. Si estas usando Windows abre el administrador de tareas y mira quién es el que te está consumiendo los recursos (si es con linux habrá una herramienta similar).  El uso intensivo del procesador también puede deberse a la falta de recursos (ram y/o disco). Es más, hace unos años Win10 tenía un bug que causa el uso al 100% de la CPU en algunos computadores. Si tú dices que testing funciona pero no en producción, yo descartaría que fuera un tema de .net y miraría hacia otro lado.

Comment: @Yussef ahi dejé cómo está cargado el ambiente de productivo, son las mismas consultas, ahora mismo estoy viendo de optimizar la bd. Tenemos 6gb de RAM

Comment: El cpu está todo virtualizado, no tengo nada en mi computadora, de hecho en mi administrador de tareas tengo 30% de cpu aprox